# PHP SQLite PDO Check if user is in table?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to create a script that checks if the provided username is in the table "users", but the "if" statement is always returned false. The users table only has the one column "username", listing all the users. What am I doing wrong?

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:db.sqlite");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username from users where username = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $user);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    //in the table
}
else{
    //not in the table
}
```

The whole script:

```
<?php
require_once 'mclogin.class.php';
$api = new MinecraftAPI();
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pword'];
if($api->login($user, $password)){
print $user;
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:db.sqlite");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username from users where username = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $user);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    echo "You are whitelisted";
}
else{
    echo "You are not whitelisted";
}

}else{
echo "Bad login";
}
?>
```

the page that send the info:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <form name="input" action="login.do.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
Password: <input type="password" name="pword">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like the username isn't found!  Have you checked that?  Your code looks fine, assuming `$user` is set somewhere.

Comment: @Brad The $user is set from a post variable just above this, which prints fine, and the username is definitely in the table. How else would the username not be found?

Comment: If you use query-parameters, you must omit the single quotes. So it's not `':name'` it's just `:name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Note:***

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last **DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, **this behaviour is not guaranteed**
>    **for all databases and should not be relied on for portable**
>   ***applications.***

You should use the below instead, just use the `fetch()` method to check whether the result is empty.

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:db.sqlite");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT 1 from users where username = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $user);
$stmt->execute();

// use fetch instead of rowCount
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
  // in the table
} else {
  // not in the table
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you, and everyone else. I wasn't expecting such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 2 to

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username from users where username = :name");
```

and it will work. The whole idea behind using parameters in PDO is that they get automatically quoted if needed in a SQL injection safe manner.

For purposes such as yours I usually use:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) from users where username = :name");
```

this will return a result I can always use directly in an if directly after because it will return one if user exists, 0 if it doesn't or false on a database error.

Comment: Still false when it should be true :(

Comment: @Jeremy can you `var_dump($user)` please? And also check if it really exists in your database, you might have posted an extra space or something and the comparison will not work that way unless you `trim($user)` first.

Comment: [Database dump](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?y1sr6jxdi2drgo7)  The dump of `$user` is a post feld, whatever you enter in the box on the previous page. For me it is "jj3502". I've added the whole script to the OP.

Comment: @Jeremy try my other suggestion, as stated in the documentation you shouldn't rely on rowCount() being correct.